# Relation between RAM usage in Task Manager Processes and Performance

Tags: task-manager

Is the amount of ram shown in the performance graph, 5.5 GB in my case :

[image]

the sum of the ram used by programs shown in processes :

[image]

Somehow I find it hard to believe that those 6MB will amount to 4GB and when I close firefox for example it seems the graph in performance falls down by much more than 830MB.

Is it just an impression, or are the values in Task Manager/Processes systematically lower than real usage ?

Edit.: Here is also the RAMMapp. Paging file is still disabled.

[image]

Comment: It appears you have the page file disabled. You should reconsider, especially with as little as 8 GB of RAM. With the page file disabled, Windows cannot efficiently make use of physical memory.

Comment: Thx, I was experimenting with that because I read somewhere that using the page file slows down the system since the hard disk is much slower than ram, and that it could be disabled if your ram was sufficient for your system use. 20+ firefox tabs and a vm, bringing the ram at 70%, seems to be already critical for this machine.

Comment: you used the wrong tools for memory measuring. Post a picture of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) (Use Count tab without any sorting).

Comment: @magicandre1981 I added the RAMMap picture

Comment: 2.65 GB are used by mapped files (DLLs, exe other loaded files). Go in "Physical Pages" tab, in Filter select "in Use" is "Mapped Files". Here look which data get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are using more than 5.5 GB of memory. 7.9GB of memory is committed.

Windows 10 compresses memory to make more RAM being allocated while less ram is actually used. In addition, memory is freed by paging it. The 830 MB is in use in system memory at that time, but Firefox can be using more memory, where the other parts are either compressed or paged. So when you close firefox, it is possible that more ram is freed. Its removed out of the page file.

Windows predicts what RAM you are going to use and will compress memory that you are likely not to need soon. By closing firefox, you switch to another program, and as such windows is likely managing its RAM to allocate for the change which may seem as more memory becoming free.

Comment: Actually, only 5.7 GB is committed, out of 7.9. There’s also no compressed memory in the screenshot. There’s nothing in the page file either, because it’s disabled. // I think an *actual* answer to this question should be about mapped files, what private working set (AKA the memory column) is etc blah. Calculating memory usage isn’t easy.